# Correlation and feature selection

Tags: feature-selection, correlation

I'm trying to learn from example on the internet. I choose the **Iris** dataset.

When I checked for correlation, I saw that there was a correlation between '*petal length*' and '*petal width*'. But when I run RFE to select only 3 features, it took both these 2 features.

So, my question is

Is that normal? 
Doesn't correlation data contribute much to your model?

PS: correlation value is 0.96

Comment: can you tell us that correlation outcome?
if it is strong or weak, Positive or Negative?

Comment: correlation value is 0.96. So I say it's pretty strong

Comment: almost equal to one, which signifies that they are positive and strongly correlated.

Comment: yeah, but when I run feature selection by RFE, it still choose both these 2 correlated features

Comment: I've answered the question, do let me know if you have any doubt regarding the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we were discussing above regarding the correlation, yes it is very important factor which would play an important role in selecting the features which are useful in explaining the **Target Variable**.

The RFE works like this, it would take all the features which ever are significant is explaining the Target Variable, if you take these 2 features separately and do the check then obviously they both are shown as significant features.

Before going to that step as you have done Correlation analysis and you should have eliminated one of the variable before giving to the model. The outcome of RFE is also correct as it was treating all the features independently.

Now you need to remove the features which are strongly correlated because if two features explain the same thing then the model would be biased towards those features and you might end-up getting **Wrong Insights**. So, strongly correlated features are highly recommended to be eliminated before doing RFE.

Comment: hmm no problem. Now understood it right? if you are stuck somewhere, will try to help you.